# Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at calendar.events.list

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, dialogflow-es

I am trying to delete event from google calendar, i have list all event in a specific time and extract the id if event
the code execute these correctly but when reach to delete method it throws "unhandeled rjection error" and "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at calendar.events.list"

```
function deleteEvent(agent){

    // Use the Dialogflow's date and time parameters to create Javascript Date instances, 'dateTimeStart' and 'dateTimeEnd',
    // which are used to specify the appointment's time.
    const appointmentDuration = 1;// Define the length of the appointment to be one hour.
    const dateTimeStart = convertParametersDateD(agent.parameters.date, agent.parameters.time);
    const dateTimeEnd = addHours(dateTimeStart, appointmentDuration);
    const appointmentTimeString = getLocaleTimeString(dateTimeStart);
    const appointmentDateString = getLocaleDateString(dateTimeStart);


    //Check the availability of the time slot and delete appointment if the time slot is available on the calendar
    return deleteCalendarEvent(dateTimeStart,dateTimeEnd).then(() => {
        agent.add(`Got it. I delete your appointment scheduled on ${appointmentDateString} at ${appointmentTimeString} and i send the sendNotifications. See you soon. Good-bye.`);
}).catch(() => {
    agent.add(`Sorry, we are not booked on ${appointmentDateString} at ${appointmentTimeString}. Please choose another time and date`);
});

}//deleteEvent functin

function deleteCalendarEvent(dateTimeStart,dateTimeEnd){
    console.log("delete calender event function");

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        calendar.events.list({  // List all events in the specified time period
            auth: serviceAccountAuth,
            calendarId: calendarId,
            timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
            timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
        }, (err, calendarResponse) => {
            // Check if there exists any event on the calendar given the specified the time period
            if (calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
            var lstOfEvent = calendarResponse.data.items;////all the events
    console.log(lstOfEvent);
    console.log('id= '+lstOfEvent[0]['id']);
    eventId=lstOfEvent[0]['id'];
    /////delete
    calendar.events.delete({

        auth: serviceAccountAuth,
        calendarId: calendarId,

        eventId:eventId
    }, (err, event) => {
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(event);
}
        );
/////delete
} else {
    reject(err);
}
});
});

}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the line that the error occurs?

Comment: if (calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0

Comment: note: var lstOfEvent = calendarResponse.data.items;////all the events
    console.log(lstOfEvent);
    console.log('id= '+lstOfEvent[0]['id']);                                                                                                                                                                                                  these line executed correctly

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your situation, for the error of ``Cannot read property 'data'``, how about modifying it to ``if (calendarResponse.data && calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {``? I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution for your issue. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: i have tried this also,, the same problem

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.